# Unity is not loading on login

Tags: unity, compiz, configuration, login, alacarte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Since yesterday I am trying solve this problem. I was working the whole day on my PC and had to reboot it in the evening. Since then it came up without unity after login. So I have no panel, no window-decorations.
I used to run unity-3D. When I select the 2D equivalent everything works fine.
Also I can switch to `tty1`, export the display location and run `unity`. This gives the output I attached to the bottom. I do not know where that information is going to while I login from the login-screen.
So after that unity is running just fine.

I tried to help myself and reinstalled all the unity-packages. Also I was thinking if my customized menus would be the problem. I ran `alacarte` yesterday to change some application descriptions so that I can find the easily using the unity lens.

This is what works:

- run unity manually from tty1
- login as guest (unity starts as usual)
- choose unity-2d (working)

These are the main questions:

- where does the unity-output go to while login?
- how do I reset all its configuration?
- how do I reset gnome-menue's configuration?

Thank you!

Attached, unit-sdtout and -stderr:

**stdout**

```
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
WARN  2012-02-09 10:18:33 glib.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 invalid (NULL) pointer instance

Screen geometry changed:
   0x0x1680x1050

Couldn't find a perfect decorator match; trying all decorators
Starting unity-window-decorator
WARN  2012-02-09 10:18:35 unity.favorites FavoriteStoreGSettings.cpp:121 Unable to load desktop file: /home/simon/.local/share/applications/evolution.desktop
WARN  2012-02-09 10:18:35 unity.favorites FavoriteStoreGSettings.cpp:121 Unable to load desktop file: /home/simon/.local/share/applications/anki.desktop
DEBUG 2012-02-09 10:18:36 glib <unknown>:0 Setting to primary screen rect: x=0 y=0 w=1680 h=1050
WARN  2012-02-09 10:19:33 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method InfoRequest proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/music does not exist
WARN  2012-02-09 10:19:33 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method SetActive proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/music does not exist
WARN  2012-02-09 10:19:33 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method InfoRequest proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/files does not exist
WARN  2012-02-09 10:19:33 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method SetActive proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/files does not exist
WARN  2012-02-09 10:19:34 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method InfoRequest proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/commands does not exist
WARN  2012-02-09 10:19:34 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method SetActive proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/commands does not exist
WARN  2012-02-09 10:19:34 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method InfoRequest proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/applications does not exist
WARN  2012-02-09 10:19:34 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method SetActive proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/applications does not exist
WARN  2012-02-09 10:19:35 unity.iconloader IconLoader.cpp:509 Unable to load contents of file:///usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/places/svg/category-installed.svg: Fehler beim Öffnen der Datei: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
WARN  2012-02-09 10:19:35 unity.iconloader IconLoader.cpp:509 Unable to load contents of file:///usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/places/svg/category-available.svg: Fehler beim Öffnen der Datei: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden <engl.:"file not found"
```

**stdout**

```
unity-panel-service: Kein Prozess gefunden <engl.:"no process found"
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.01.upgrade
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.02.upgrade
Initializing core options...done
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing snap options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing scale options...done
Initializing session options...done
unity-panel-service: Kein Prozess gefunden
Initializing unityshell options...done
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
```

Comment: So what is it then and how to solve this issue?